# Is it possible and legal to push updates to Ionic apps?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ionic-framework

I've been looking at some comparisons between Flutter and Ionic.

One "disadvantage" for Flutter said that Flutter apps have to go through the app approval process with every update.

So it implicitly claims that Ionic apps updates can be pushed without going through an approval process.

My questions are:

1. Is it indeed technically possible (out of the box) to push new versions for Ionic apps without re-approving the app? (meaning: push updated JS/HTML/assets that would be "saved" into the app, as if the app had originally been published with them).
2. Is it (currently) permitted by Google's and Apple's T&Cs?
3. Is it a standard practice to push updates this way, or do developers normally re-publish new versions of their apps using the stores' procedures, even when working with Ionic?

To clarify - I'm referring to updates of JS and assets; not to updates of native code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but this might help:

Ionic does offer a service called [appflow](https://ionic.io/appflow) which does exactly that (among other things):

> Send live updates to users without waiting on app store approval

and

> Deliver a better mobile experience for your users by sending updates directly to them in real-time, without waiting on app store approval.

The last time I checked (which was a couple of years ago) the [iOS App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) did allow pushing updates outside of the official review process **but explicitly only for web-based content**, but I can't find that section in the newest version of the guidelines.

The Google Play Store is generally less restrictive and as long as it doesn't impact performance, privacy, security etc. I think they'll be OK with it (but I also can't find that explicitly stated).

So since Ionic offers it as a service I'm inclined to say that it's (still) allowed. But if you want more certainty I suggest contacting Ionic, I'm sure they can give you more information.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how long it usually takes for Google (and Apple?) to approve an update that doesn't require additional permissions or policy changes (i.e. doesn't suddenly target children under 13, etc.). My concern is that a major bug (e.g. crash) is found after release and that it would take days to publish a fix.